# jQuery dialog click outside close causes dialog to re-open

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

On focus of a text box I display a modal dialog using jQuery.  When the dialog is closed, focus goes back to the text box, which then displays the dialog again.  Is it possible to stop that from happening?

In the close funtion of the dialog I've tried...

```
event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
event.returnValue = false;
```

...but those won't work because they are stopping the event that closed the dialog, not the focus event which is a new event.

This appears to be an IE only issue - it doesn't happen in chrome and edge because they do not return focus to the original input control.  Any ideas?

```
$ctl.focus(function (e) {
    var $popup = jQuery("<div><input type=\"text\"></input></div>");
    $popup.dialog({
            title: 'test',
            closeOnEscape: true,
            position: {
                of: $ctl,
                my: "left top",
                at: "left bottom"
            },
            open: function (event, ui) {               

                //Close the dialog when clicking outside (on the modal overlay) - requires the dialog to be in modal format
                jQuery(".ui-widget-overlay").click(function () {
                    $popup.dialog("close");

                    event.stopPropagation();
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

                    event.returnValue = false;
                });

            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                jQuery(this).dialog("destroy").remove();
            },
            minHeight: 10,
            minWidth: 10,
            modal:true
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have immediate access to IE at the moment, but I think removing focus should work.

$(event.target).blur();